# Spring Rest-API - 403 forbidden error response

Tags: java, spring, rest

I,m new to spring, I,m writing REST API. I/'m getting 403 forbidden error for delete, put. Following is the sample I'm working on.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{noteId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity noteIdPut(
            @PathVariable("Id") String Id,
            Note note)
            throws Exception {
        return service.updateNote(Id, note);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add these filter line in web.xml.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,authorization,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll try and let you know

Comment: Lifesaver! I was debugging a similar issue and it worked like magic, could have saved me a few hours if I came straight here.

Comment: how to achieve this in java file?