# DELETE 403 (Forbidden) error spring-mvc and rest implementation

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

when i try to use `DELETE` method i am geeing `403 delete forbidden`  error .

i am using **spring-mvc+rest implementation**

i tried to add some xml tags in my `web.xml` file as suggested in some other post

as follows

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but did not work for me.
**is there any other configuration to do in spring-servlet.xml or in web.xml ?**

can any one help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Rest-API - 403 forbidden error response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068019/spring-rest-api-403-forbidden-error-response)

Comment: can you post the full error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable CSRF in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

**http.csrf().disable()**

**However, this could be a system security flaw. Be careful!**

code below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()     //  <<------- PUT THIS IN YOUR CODE
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/primeiro_acesso/**", "/upload", "/testes/upload", "/files/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me (adding the CSRF disable) -- my GET requests were working fine but a new PUT request was giving a 403 Forbidden. Thank you.

Comment: not working for me. All methods are accesible but DELETE methods returns 403

Comment: Not a very good idea...